# Why does this function affect a non-global variable outside of its scope in JS?

Tags: javascript, execution

I have the following code:

```
function control_function() {
    let data = { inputs: [ 'one', 'two'] };
    level_one(data);
    console.log(data);
} control_function();

function level_one(data) {
    data.inputs.shift();
}
```

And you can see I'm outputting `data`, it should give me `['one', 'two']` back, instead it gives me `['two']`, meaning that the function `level_one` has, for some reason, affected data that it shouldn't have access to (to write, it has access to it to read, since I'm passing it to the function). I'm signaling to JS that this `let data` is only to be used within the `control_function` scope and is not to be affected by other functions.

In PHP, this doesn't happen and it makes sense for it not to happen, yet it happens here, which means there's some underlying basic concept I don't understand. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "In any other programming language, this doesn't happen" Wrong. What makes you think that? Objects and arrays etc. are passed by references in other programming languages just as well and you would observe the exact same behavior (Java, C#, ..)

Comment: @marsze Sorry, I meant PHP. Is there any reason for why this was chosen and how can I make it work so that any function that uses the data I pass has it as a copy, not as a reference, so that my original data doesn't get changed? Also, this smells bad, it feels that if I have to pass an object by value, something is wrong.

Comment: If you want to modify the contents of the array without affecting the original, you should simply make a copy/clone first.

Comment: @marsze Naturally and here's the code: `let copied_data = $.extend({}, data);` but doesn't this feel like a cheat?

Comment: Arrays are objects. If you want to **modify** a passed object inside a function, but **keep** original, then yes you have to make a clone. You can also clone arrays with `clone = array.slice(0)`.